# Add sorting function on table tag

Tags: php, laravel, html-table

I'm using Laravel 5.4

So I wanted to know if I'm able to sort things in my table without actually using queries.

Here's my table structure:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Total Earnings</th>
        <th>Quantity Sold</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @forelse($solditems as $solditem) 
            <tr>
                <td>{{$solditem->item_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$solditem->item}}</td>
                <td>{{$solditem->subtotal}}</td>
                <td>{{$solditem->qty}}</td>
                <td>{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($solditem->created_at)->format('j F Y h:i A')}}</td>
            </tr>
        @empty
        @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery Data table.
see docs [here](https://datatables.net/).

Here are links for `CSS` and `JS`

http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

So, what you need to do is add following script to your file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

You need to add `id="myTable"` to your table element.

**UPDATE**

First download the files from links above,

put `css` file  inside `project/public/css/` directory and `js` file to `project/public/js/` directory then, add like

**CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="customTable">
    ....
</table>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.customTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Pleasure ! Anyway congrats

Comment: I'm kinda confused. I wanted to ask something for confirmation, is there something else I need to do instead of modifying my script? The columnDefs format doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you explain what's the problem in detail ?

Comment: About this plug-in codes that is starting with `jQuery.extend`. I'm note sure where to put it, I'm trying the `numeric-comma`. As of now, I reverted again to the script you provided.

Comment: Adding the `columnDefs` inside the `DataTable` parameters still doesn't work. By the way, thanks for sticking up with my problem! Somehow I'm having ideas on how this works.

Comment: If you need customization for ordering of particular table column other wise you can use default case which will allow to sort by every column.